# DataTables: createdCell doesn't work on page load (after it works)

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using datatables and I'd like to show an icon in a column (based on the value in the column data).
I've written a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var oTable = $("#initiativeTable").DataTable({
    "serverSide":true,
    "processing":true,
    "searching": false,
    "ordering": true,
    "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
    "ajax": '${basePath}/cns/initiative/table.json?teams=${teams}&fields=${fields}&search=${search}',
    "columns": [
                { "data": "id_init" },{ "data": "parent_name_init" },{ "data": "name_cust" },{ "data": "name_init" },{ "data": "code_paf" },{ "data": "name_team" },{ "data": "pa_name_emp" },{ "data": "pgm_name_emp" },{ "data": "pm_name_emp" },{ "data": "id_initstt" },{ "data": "description_contrtype" },{ "data": "description_inittype" },{ "data": "is_revised_init" }] ,
                "columnDefs": [{    "targets": 12,
                       "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                           if ( cellData == 'false' ) {
                               $(td).html("");
                             }else{
                              $(td).html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>");
                             }                               
                       }
                     }
}); 
});
```

The DataTables works fine but the column show the value of data, not the icon. If I reorder the table or go on second page of pagination, the createdCell works and the icon is showed.
It doesn't work only on the first load of the page.
What is the problem?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Matteo

Comment: use `render()` instead -> https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: Yes, with render it works even at first loading. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `createdCell` is Inside columns, check [columns.createCell](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.createdCell):

```
columns: [

          {
            data : "name_data",
            createCell: function(){
                //code
            }
          } 

]
```

You can use this code:

```
{ 
  "data": "is_revised_init",
  "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
                       if ( cellData == 'false' ) {
                           $(td).html("");
                         }else{
                          $(td).html("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>");
                         }                               
                   }

}
```

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. I used the render() like below and it works.

"targets": 12,
"render": function ( cellData, type, full, meta ) {
                               if ( cellData == 'false' ) {
                                   return "";
                                 }else{
                                  return "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>";